# How to prove that a function is decreasing?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I would like to inquire whether there is a simple way to prove that a function is decreasing or not. For example how would I prove that the function

$$Y = (X^.5 - 1)/0.5$$

is decreasing? I am not sure whether the negativity of the 2nd derivative solves this and would really like to understand the intuition better.

Comment: What is your definition of a diminishing function?

Comment: @user2566092 A function that grows, but has diminishing returns. Here is a good picture:
http://rufuspollock.org/economics/papers/media/copyright_term/works_to_welfare.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting this answer because you wanted to know the monotonicity in terms of the derivative, otherwise this answer does not make any sense as there is already a nice answer of your question.

So if a function is differentiable then the monotonicity can be described as follows.

> Let $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ be continuous function which is differentiable on $(a,b)$, then
>
> (i) $f^\prime(x)>0,\, \forall x\in (a,b)\implies f$ is (strictly) increasing on $[a,b]$
>
> (ii) $f^\prime(x)<0,\, \forall x\in (a,b)\implies f$ is (strictly) decreasing on $[a,b]$
>
> (iii) $f^\prime(x)=0,\, \forall x\in (a,b)\implies f$ is constant on $[a,b]$.

For your problem $f(x)=\frac{1}{0.5}(x^{0.5}-1)=2(\sqrt{x}-1)$. Clearly $f$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and $f^\prime(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}},\,\forall x\in(0,\infty)$. Also $f^\prime(x)>0$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$. Thus $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, let's it's easier to go directly from the definition. Note that $\frac{(x^{1/2}-1)}{1/2} = 2 x^{1/2} - 2$. Note that $-2$ is constant. Now, consider $x_2 > x_1$ for any $x_2, x_1$ and compare $2x_2^{1/2}$ to $2x_1^{1/2}$:

$$\frac{2x_2^{1/2}}{2x_1^{1/2}} = \left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right)^{1/2}.$$

Since $x_2 > x_1$, we have

$$\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right)^{1/2} > 1.$$

So starting at any point in the domain ($x_1$), if we go any distance to the right (to $x_2$), the function gets bigger. Now, simply show that it gets bigger without bound (in other words, it is not increasing to a limit of zero).